# What could be my mistake when installing wine at Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, wine

Recently, I have installed wine using

```
sudo aptitude install wine
```

, accepting proposals from the aptitude and running further commands recommended in related answers. Now, I am trying it at the same type of PC which is in the same status: freshly upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. However the aptitude cannot resolve conflicts and, in the further commands, the first difference is between

```
as_the_root@PC1:/home/me$ sudo wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key -O Release.key
2020-04-28 00:20:19 URL:https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key [1089/1089] -> "Release.key" [1]
as_the_root@PC1:/home/me$ sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
OK
as_the_root@PC1:/home/me$
```

and

```
as_the_root@PC2:/home/me$ sudo wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key -O Release.key
2020-05-08 15:08:50 URL:https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key [1089/1089] -> "Release.key" [1]
as_the_root@PC2:/home/me$ sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
bash: Release.key: Permission denied
as_the_root@PC2:/home/me$
```

.  The PC2 now responds

```
as_the_root@PC2:/home/me$ wine --version
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libesets_pac.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
wine-3.0 (Ubuntu 3.0-1ubuntu1)
as_the_root@PC2:/home/me$
```

.
Renaming

```
~/.wine
```

according to the 1st answer to [Wine Installation Mistake](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876977/wine-installation-mistake?rq=1) and repeating  whole the procedure has not helped to recognize the Release.key . The procedure according to the 3rd answer (Tutorial) to [Can't install Wine Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097724/cant-install-wine-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1) installed 1 GiB data, however the PC2 responds the same.
What could be the mistake? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @N0rbert: Thanks, the difference of answers between identical PCs, which I ask in the question, concerns the commands that you recommend in that answer. Therefore, I cannot answer yes/no to you. After those installations that aptitude has done (with my agreement), it is hard to get to know. Moreover, that wine in the PC2 has "recovered", as I am writing in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try a clean wine install.

Try with

```
$ sudo apt purge wine
```

then try with official WineHQ repository

First enable 32bits architecture

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Here you Download and add the repository keys

```
$ wget -O - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now add the repository

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

then update repos

```
$ sudo apt update
```

and the last step, install the WineHQ package

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Now you can test your version

```
$ wine --version
```

Here is the [link](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) to the official Webpage

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to run an *.exe file with wine has requested installing Wine_Mono and Wine_Gecko and, for my purposes, wine now works. The answers

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libesets_pac.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored
```

were due to the ESET antivirus program; it's upgrading has repaired it.
Now, wine-5.0 is present. Those my installation attempts took 2.3 GiB on disk. Installing from the beginning according to Giovanni Rodríguez answer would certainly be more economical. Many users would certainly appreciate that installation be available in Ubuntu Software.